# Background set to 100% height still repeats

Tags: css, background, cross-browser

I have the following CSS code.

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #1468b3;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#2F2727), to(#1468b3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1468b3);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1468b3);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1468b3);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1468b3);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#2F2727", endColorstr="#1468b3");
}
```

Regardless of the content of the page there should be a nice gradient that stretches from the top to the bottom of the browser window. This screenshot illustrates the issue:

[image]

I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

Adding

```
no-repeat;
```

Cancels out the gradient and instead the background is the solid `#1468b3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `html { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Clarification: Scaling elements using % bases the size of the element (in your case, `body`) on the size of its parent (`html`). By default, the `html` tag has `height:auto`, so your `body` is only taking up the room necessitated by the content. **Incidentally**, because it seems you want the gradient to remain fixed to the page, you may want to add a `background-attachment: fixed;` to the `body` styles.